# Change an imageview when it is clicked

Tags: android

I want the imageview with the Id = soundtoggle to switch to R.drawable.sound_on under the if condition and otherwise to R.drawable.sound_off. But i am not able to do it. Please help

```
    package com.twodwarfs.fallanimation;

    import com.tmp.animation.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ToggleActivity extends Activity 
    { 
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
        final ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.soundtoggle);
        img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.soundtoggle)
                {
                    img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_on));
                }
                else 
                {
                    img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_off));
                }
            }});
        }
     }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/home_screen">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/musictoggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/soundtoggle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/music_off"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/soundtoggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/musictoggle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playbutton"
    android:src="@drawable/sound_off" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" 
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/soundtoggle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
    android:background="@drawable/play"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />
```

my full xml which consists of 3 buttons play,sound and music

Comment: Take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector/14024007#14024007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of setting background

```
img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_on));
```

you need to setImageResource

```
img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
```

Also your v.getId() will always return the same id, so you need another flag to track

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    private boolean toggle=false;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(toggle)
        {
             img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_on));
             toggle=false;
        }
        else 
        {
             img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_off));
             toggle=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please specify what should be the xlm version.I mean should it be a button or an imageview...

Comment: In xml you have two attributes android:bacground and android:src if you supply each with an image resource, the android:src will show above the android:bacground

Comment: and here you wont need to check if(v.getId() == R.id.soundtoggle) as it will always return true, because you provided this clickListener only to this view

Comment: Man it is still not working..can u help me out coz i really need to deliver this project in time

Comment: what is not working? does it generate error? post your logcat

Comment: nothing happens when i click on the imageview with the id of soundtoggle                                                         `enter code here`                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/soundtoggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/musictoggle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/sound_off" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" 
        />

Comment: print a log in onClick and under if and under else does it print?

Comment: nope nothing happens..log.e does not print anything in the logcat..it is not even recognising the click

Answer (score 0):

Your if-else is invalid. Make something like this:

```
private boolean buttonClick = true;

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.soundtoggle)
    {
       if(buttonClick){
           img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_on));
       } else{
           img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_off));
       }
       buttonClick = !buttonClick;    
    }
}
```

Every time you click the image you see "sound_on" image. Because you set that on image click

Answer (score 0):

Use this
 `star3.setImageResource(R.drawable.unclickstar);`

instead of 
`img1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sound_off));`