# How to change background of button on tap?

Tags: android

I am having a button I want to do toggle on button like on and off,What I required is I am having two backgroundimages.

When I first time tap on button first background image should be done and on second time second background image should be changed like in toggle button.

Anybody please help me as I am new to android.

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button Button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector/14024007#14024007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTag to do that.

First>

```
Button1.setTag("ON");
```

and secondly in your onclicklistener add this:

```
if (v.getTag().toString().equals("ON")) {
            v.setTag("OFF");
             v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }else {
            v.setTag("ON");
             v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher2);
        }
```

Comment: I dont have toggle button..I am having simple button,I given example of toggle button..

Comment: I don't get it. You can do this with a simple button too. You can do this almost each view. Did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml file in the drawable with the following code and change the background of the button to this drawable

customButton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image_not_pressed">      </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed"></item>
</selector>
```

Then add background to the image

```
<ImageView
    android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"
    android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/customButtom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the `setSelected` state for the `Button` and change the image by checking if it `isSelected` on `Button` click

Try using

```
Button button = new Button(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (v.isSelected())
                {
                  v.setSelected(false);
                }
                else
                {
                  v.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: will you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`,change image on the surface of the ImageButton by the `setImageResource(int)` method.