# Bubbles like whatsapp, viber, facebook chat

Tags: android, android-layout, whatsapp, viber

I am trying to create a chat bubble like viber, whatsapp and facebook chat have. Please look at this screenshot:

[image]

The last bubble does not have an arrow. I am wondering if those bubbles are a 9-patch images or something which is made programmatically. I have googled a while but I cannot find exactly this image, tho it is the same in many apps (viber, whatsapp).

My second question is, how do I create that bottom line in the bubbles which shows if the message has been delivered. Is it an ImageButton with Html.fromHtml() inside (a  for bottom line)? Is it a LinearLayout with two TextViews?

I am also searching for these ✓✓. Viber and WhatsApp have the same, but it does not seem to be utf. Is it an image maybe?

Thx.

Comment: The bubbles can me made using patch 9 backgrounds, also the ticks are probably images aligned to the right/bottom of whatever layout is used.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if those bubbles are a 9-patch images or something
>   which is made programmatically

The bubble (with the the arrow and without) are nine-patches.

> My second question is, how do I create that bottom line in the bubbles which shows if the message has been delivered.

the message status at the bottom of this bubble is an `ImageView` that changes from no ✓ to an image with one ✓ and then when the message arrived to the receiver the two ✓✓ image is shown.

Comment: So it is basically:
<LinearLayout with background of that nine-patch image>

Comment: It can be any other layout as well, but basically yeah.

Comment: you have to remember that 9-patches come to aid you in you application design, and each time you can use them and avoid designing in code, do that!

Comment: So it is basically:
<LinearLayout with background of that nine-patch image>
  <TextView for chat-Text>
  <LinearLayout>
    <ImageView for the ✓✓>
    <TextView with text for delivery?>

I tried to reproduce it like that. Unluckily I am not able to make this LinearLayout clickable like an ImageButton with android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" because Background is already the nine patch image.

Comment: Right... So you have to create a selector that consists of several 9-patch images for different states of the bubble and apply it as a background, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector