# LinearLayout click animation

Tags: animation, onclick, android-linearlayout

So, I want to create Custom Views, set Linear Layouts equal to them and, I want to make them clickable.
So, when I click that Linear Layout View, I want it to have the click animation, the same way List Item has(it goes orange and you have that feeling that you clicked it). How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Selectors that is the word you should be googling for ;) this is not considered an animation but a state.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Answer (score 0):

Very, very late.

Anyone who finds this thread, use this.

```java
findViewById(R.id.next_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Define your animator here
            Animator scale = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1, 1.5f, 1),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1, 1.5f, 1)
                    );
            scale.setDuration(1000);
            scale.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).