# Android ListView with adapter to highlight selected item row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Sorry if this is answered already, but I can't find anything and I can't specify my search very well.
I have a list view in Fragment which uses an adapter to populate it, and I want the list view item rows, to get highlighted for a second when they get clicked, and I want them to get highlighted for just half a second then get back to normal (basically like a feedback that the item row is clicked), like the default call log works in the phone app.
My adapter is exending ArrayAdapter.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the adapter getView()

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    CallStats call = callsArray.get(position);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_call, null);
    initializeViews(holder, convertView);
    setViewsEntries(holder, call);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: you want selector behavior or change color for 1 second only?

Comment: more like change alpha

Comment: is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Comment: I dont think this will work in item row in ListView with adapter

Comment: why not? you need change row's background of your list to one Selector `xml` file, i do this in my project

Comment: where do you give this xml in the adapter then?

Comment: can you post `getView` method on adapter class?

Comment: there, in my question

Comment: change background of `item_row_call` to your `xml` selector

Comment: @БориславМинчев will make it more clear i am not getting your question properly

Comment: are you sure? can you post selector file and `item_row_call` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "setSelector" like :

```
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.black);
```

Comment: you have to add this line just after: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: that works when I removed the background of the item_row.xml, but it changes the color permanently, I want it to be changed just for a half second

Comment: To do it for a short interval of time , probably you have to use thread.

Comment: Also , if you remove the setSelector line from the code , an orangish color is automatically taken , which stays for a very short time - as per your requirement . I would request you to kindly check once removing the setSelector line from you code snippet .

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem, turns out the item row when clicked don't get highlighted for a moment because in the item_row.xml I have set a background, without a background it works fine, without any additional code