# When a button is clicked, how to make its background image will change for a few seconds before reverting back?

Tags: android, button, background-image

I've placed this code on my `onClickListener`:

```
btnListenC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lisbtnpressed);
```

But from here, how do I make it so that the drawable `'lisbtnpressed'` changes back to its original image after a few seconds please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easier with an XML file in your **drawable** folder (mybutton.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mydrawable />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/otherdrawable" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/redcolor" />
</selector>
```

and use this in button xml code

```
android:background:@drawable/mybutton
```

As you can see in the first piece of code you can have a different drawable (color, image...) for each button state. The button states can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

With this approach you don't need to use any code.

Comment: Thanks! What's item android:drawable="@color/redcolor" for? Do I need to indicate a color of some kind or something?

Comment: @Fuchsia that is the resource you refer in `colors.xml`.

Comment: @Fuchsia Drawable can be an image or a color. That last item is just an example, but as you can see it has no 'state' attribute, meaning that's the default drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector

[android button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)

or use `OnTouchListener` on `ACTION_DOWN` change to `lisbtnpressed` on `ACTION_UP` set to default

```
 btnListenC.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 switch(event.getAction())
 {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                  // change
             btnListenC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lisbtnpressed);
   break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                 // set to original
             btnListenC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lisbtnoriginal);   
   break; 
    }
 return true;
   }
 });
```