# Change ImageView source for some time after button click

Tags: android, button, imageview

I have two buttons and one imageview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dog"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dogsec" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/barkk"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dog"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bark" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/rrrr"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/barkk"
    android:layout_below="@+id/barkk"
    android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/rrr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

a) I need to make Imageview change its' source to another one(I mean the image's default state is picture1, it should show picture2 and go back to picture1) on button "barkk" click. It should not show picture2 as long as barkk is pressed.

b) and I need to display picture3 as long as button rrrr is pressed.

I use exactly ImageView which should change its' source depending on case a) or b) as it is described above.

Help me please. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need selector xml file, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan "I use exactly ImageView which should change its' source depending on case a) or b) as it is described above." That is why selector is not applicable, there are no buttons, but ImageView only

Comment: why not? change `drawable` in selector file and set to background of your image, if you don't want this you need handle that on your code with `onTouchListener`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan, do you want to say that it is possible to connect a separate ImageView with a button via selector?

Comment: you wan change another image with clicking to button? so no,its not possible , you need do this on code

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
  {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage);
    }
}
};
```