# How to programmatically display a view in center of another view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a `buttonView1` and a `customView1` that only draws a small circle. in my `main_layout` only `buttonView1` is visible.

How can I programmatically display `customView1` in center of `buttonView1` when button is clicked.

attention: we dont want to change button background. we want to show a new view (customView or any other view like editText) on another view (button) when button is pressed.

---

layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

activity code

```
    ///...
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonView1);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonView1:
                // do sth here
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
///...
```

Comment: Show your code what you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android button selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)

Comment: Why don't you try to use selector as background of your button? Do you really need another view for this?

Comment: is `customView1` a drawable?

Comment: No, I dont want to change the button background. `customview1` is a custom view and i want to develop it to interact with user

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
yourView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: is `button1` parent of `customView1`?

Comment: No RelativeLayout is the parrent and also you have to put button1 in center of your relativelayout if not... customize with margins ofcource with layoutparams

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MoveView() {

        float a = parent_view.getWidth() / 2;
        final ValueAnimator positionAnimator =
                ValueAnimator.ofFloat(current_view.getX(), a);
        positionAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        positionAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float x = (Float) positionAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                current_view.setX(x);
            }
        });

        positionAnimator.setDuration(100);
        positionAnimator.start();
    }
```

parent_view is the view in whose center you would like to place your current_view.

Hope that Helps.