# How do I change a button image "play" and "stop" programmatically?

Tags: android

How do I change a button image `play` and `stop` programmatically?

```
public void eventOccured(int id) {
                Log.i("sat", "Clicked on " + id);




                if (id==4){


                    if (sound_Off){
                        sound_Off= false;
                        if (editor != null) {
                             editor.putBoolean("prefSoundOnOff",false);
                             editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
                             }

                    } else {
                        sound_Off= true;
                        if (editor != null) {
                             editor.putBoolean("prefSoundOnOff",true);
                             editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
                             }

                    }
                }       
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you know that your code does not apply to question?

Answer (score 1):

use `findViewById()` to get your imageview and cast it to imageview.

Then you can set the Image in the if statements.

```
 ImageView imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);
 imgView.setImageResource(R.id.myicon);
```

Where `myImageViewId` is the ID of the imageview, set in your xml layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector in the drawables with true and false options with eatch image,
then apply the selector to the imageview with setImageResource

edit: example i saw in other thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024007/3419242