# Changing the Background on Item Selected of a Spinner Dropdown List

Tags: android, background, ontouchlistener, onitemselectedlistener

I have a spinner that needs to change background images when touched (or pressed).

I have the style set so that the correct image shows, but I cannot for the life of me get the background image to change.

**My spinner code on my activity_main xml is this:**

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="@style/SpinnerDropdown1"
    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:entries="@array/counties"/>
```

**this is my @style/SpinnerDropDown1 code:**

```
<Resources>
  <style name="SpinnerDropdown1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/unpressed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
  </style>
</Resources
```

**and here is my MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

     final ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.counties, R.layout.my_spinner_items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setSelection(0);

    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            return false;
        }
    });

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int pos, long id) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 1:
                    Intent j = new Intent (MainActivity.this, JasperOptions.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LakeOptions.class);
                    startActivity(k);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent l = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LaporteOptions.class);
                    startActivity(l);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Intent n = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewtonOptions.class);
                    startActivity(n);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PorterOptions.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {


        }

    });

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

 }
}
```

Comment: you can use selector, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Comment: Just for clarification, I create an xml for the selecter and put it in the drawable file, then call it under the background of my spinner?

Comment: Would I still need the onTouchListener in the MainActivity?

Comment: no, you don't need that

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! I can turn my SR. Project in tomorrow. Wish me Luck!