# How to Higlight a button on a Click in android >

Tags: android, button

I have button in that i set **DrawableTop** as `home icon` and **Background** as `Null.` Now I have click event to that button, when i click that button remains constant, I need to make some hignlights when clicking that button. This is my XML code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="15sp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
    android:text="@string/home"
    android:textColor="#004040"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

this is what my button look likes, I have two buttons and one textview in this picture[image]

Comment: have you tried using a drawable?

Comment: @Pr38y sorry I cont get! How i use drawable here ?

Comment: for background attribute you can give one drawable that will be a xml also known as selector eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector