# How can I manage focus of textview like checkbox focus is managed in listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, focus

how can I manage focus of `textview` like checkbox focus is managed in `listview`(if i click on check box in `listitem` only checkbox is clicked and if i click on `listitem` checkbox is not clicked). what I tried is:

- `textview` focusable true. but `listitem` is then not clickable
- `textview` `focusableInTouchMode` true. but `listitem` is then not clickable

Comment: i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You may use [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) for highlight view in list.

Or if you need something more difficult(Behavior of TextView must do the same work like CheckBox) then you have two ways for resolve that

1) Use CheckBox view with param

```
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/my_custom_selector_for_state"
```

2) "remember" background color of your TextView in item object after click and set in **getView(...)** method in adapter