# How to change the button upon click ,and revert back to normal upon release the button?

Tags: java, android, button

I want my image to change the image as long as i press and hold on to the button . And when i release my finer i want it to revert back to the original image , is there a way to do this ?

```
   bTen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               bTen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.press);
               s1+="E";
               txtView.setText(s1);
           }
       });
```

i have used the above code ,but it does not revert back to original when i release my finger.

Comment: Use button selector like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own selector and add it as style for your button (in xml) example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- disabled -->        
    <item android:drawable="@color/..." android:state_enabled="false"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/..." android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/..."></item>


</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml in your drawable folder with name of image.xml with this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Then use this image.xml in your layout xml as

```
           <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image"/>
```