# no overlay is shown when clicking the button

Tags: android

I changed the style of a button using the following style

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/bg_color</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

the style was applied successfully as I wanted, but now when I click the button the blue overlay of the pressed state is no longer shown, how can I recover it?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting custom background for button and it is solid color, without state. This blue overlay comes from nine-patches of button

You should use [selector as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) or even better: [button drawable generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)