# How can I create a button that changes its background image to represent its states

Tags: android, eclipse, button, background

How can I create a button that changes its background image to represent the default, pressed or focused states?

Comment: See [android button selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector). Please do google it before asking same questions again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to do using a selector.

Create a new xml file inside the drawable folder containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_default"></item>

</selector>
```

Then refer to this selector in your Button:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_you_just_made"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Button" />
```

More documentation and other possible states can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 0):

XML drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
              android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
              android:state_focused="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
     </selector>
```

Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"  />
```

[Here in section Custom background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) is more info