# Button subclass onClick not responding

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a subclass of Button. The code is as below

```
package com.comnet.bookshelf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class myButton extends Button implements OnClickListener{
    Paint mainPaint;
    int colorArray[];
    int colorArrayAlt[];
    boolean touch=false;
    Rect bound;
    public myButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mainPaint=new Paint();
        bound=new Rect();
        defaultColorIndexArray();
    }

    public myButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mainPaint=new Paint();
        bound=new Rect();
        defaultColorIndexArray();
    }

    public myButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mainPaint=new Paint();
        bound=new Rect();
        defaultColorIndexArray();
    }
    private void defaultColorIndexArray(){
        colorArray=new int[]{
        0xFFd28181, //1
        0xFFd48787,     //2
        0xFFd68d8d, //3
        0xFFd89292, //4
        0xFFda9898, //5
        0xFFdc9e9e, //6
        0XFFdea2a2, //7
        0XFFe0a8a8,     //8
        0xFFe2adad, //9
        0XFFe3b1b1, //10
        0XFFe4b4b4, //11
        0XFFe6b9b9, //12
        0XFFe7bdbd, //13
        0XFFe9c0c0, //14
        0XFFeac3c3, //15
        0XFFebc6c6, //16
        0XFFebc7c7, //17
        0XFFecc9c9, //18
        0XFFeccaca, //19
        0XFFeccaca,     //20
        0XFFeccbcb, //21
        0XFFeccbcb      //22
        };
        colorArrayAlt=new int[]{
        0XFFeccbcb, //22
        0XFFeccbcb, //21
        0XFFeccaca, //20
        0XFFeccaca, //19
        0XFFecc9c9, //18
        0XFFebc7c7, //17
        0XFFebc6c6, //16
        0XFFeac3c3, //15
        0XFFe9c0c0, //14
        0XFFe7bdbd, //13
        0XFFe6b9b9, //12
        0XFFe4b4b4, //11
        0XFFe3b1b1, //10
        0xFFe2adad, //9
        0XFFe0a8a8, //8
        0XFFdea2a2, //7
        0xFFdc9e9e, //6
        0xFFda9898, //5
        0xFFd89292, //4
        0xFFd68d8d, //3
        0xFFd48787, //2
        0xFFd28181  //1
        };
    }
    public void setButtonColorIndexArray(int carray[], int carray_alt[]){
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvasObject) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObject);
        int draw_color[];
        if(touch==false)
        draw_color=colorArray;
        else
        draw_color=colorArrayAlt;
        int width=canvasObject.getWidth();
        int height=canvasObject.getHeight();
        double colorcount=44;
        double divheight=height;
        double f=colorcount/divheight;

        double step=0;
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++,step+=f){
        int next=(int) Math.round(step);
        if(next>43) next=43;
        else if(next<0)next=0;
        if(next<22){
        mainPaint.setColor(draw_color[next]);
        canvasObject.drawLine(0, i, width, i, mainPaint);
        }
        else{
        mainPaint.setColor(draw_color[43-next]);
        canvasObject.drawLine(0, i, width, i, mainPaint);
        }
        //int color=;
        mainPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());

        String str=this.getText().toString();
        //mainPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        mainPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        //canvasObject.drawPaint(mainPaint); 

        mainPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        mainPaint.setTextSize(20); 
        mainPaint.getTextBounds(str, 0, str.length(), bound);
        int x=(width-(bound.right-bound.left))/2;
        int y=(height+(bound.bottom-bound.top))/2;

        canvasObject.drawText(str, x, y, mainPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //Log.i("Click", "ACTION_DOWN");
        touch=true;
        this.invalidate();
        }
        else if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        touch=false;
        this.invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Clicked", "Clicked");
    }
}
```

Everything but one is working as I expected.

onClick is not responding at all. The code is as below:

```
((myButton)inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DeleteTheEntireBook();
    }
});
```

The button with default class is working fine

If you have any further question, let me know.

Comment: which Onclick is not called? one which is implemented in sub class or one which is use to delete book?

Comment: @KarnShah neither of them, The second one I have added to test the behavior.

Comment: The problem is *You have overridden **onTouchEvent***. Commmet it. You will be able to get onCllick fired

Comment: what is the purpose of Touch event?

Comment: If you wanna handle both, return FALSE from touch then only Click event will be fire. **If you return true for touchevent, the ClickListener will never get it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is You have overridden onTouchEvent.

Mark these words:

> You should return false in your OnTouchListener then your OnClickListener will be also handled.

So you might think, I will just do my thing there and return false so I can receive clicks too. If you do so, it will work, but you wont be subscribed to other upcoming touch events (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP) Therefore only option is to return true there, but then you wont receive any click events as we said previously.

So you need to **perform the click manually in the ACTION_UP with performClick()**

Tested and working code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Log.i("Click", "ACTION_DOWN");
            touch = true;
            this.invalidate();

        } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            touch = false;
            this.invalidate();
            // KEY LINE
            performClick();
        }
        return true;


    }
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: Hello ツ。Thank you for your response. Your suggestion worked. You asked a question about the reason of handling onTouchEvent. Well, I have handled it because I want to change the look of the button on touch. That is the best way I have found so far. If you know better way, can you suggest me! Thanks.

Comment: Yaa.. you can use  [selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14024007/2591002) fr that . Itz an easy way :) You just need to convert your java code to XML, though it might be difficult  :) Then you don't need onDraw as well as onTouch

Comment: @SweetWisherツ　Well, this is just a beginning of somework that I want to achieve :). It is part of my learning.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor, add the onClickListener,
and no need to `((myButton)inflatedLayout.findViewB...`

```
public myButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mainPaint=new Paint();
    bound=new Rect();
    defaultColorIndexArray();
    setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

then the overridden `onClick` in `myButton` class should be called once the button is clicked.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion. But, it didn't help. Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 0):

View.OnClickListener :Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked. 
Can you use this Code:

```
((myButton)inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    DeleteTheEntireBook();
}
```

});

Comment: Hello, Rajapandiyan JJ, that was exactly what I did. I have imported the View.OnCickListener that is why I didn't write View.OnclickListener. But thanks for taking your time.