# change color when tab on that button(selected) and get normal layout for other button

Tags: android, select, button

i am creating dynamic button in one horizontal LinearLayout. now need to change color in background when i selected and at that time other button will be change as normal default layout.
i already create like this:- [image]

my code like that :-

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
                final TextView btn = new TextView(activity);
                btn.setId(i);
                final int id_ = btn.getId();
                btn.setText("button " + id_);


                //btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
                new_addonprice_name.addView(btn, params);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*                      new_addonprice_name.removeAllViews();
                        String  aaa = updatebutton();*/
                           btn.setSelected(true);

                        Toast.makeText(activity, btn.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: hi @tej shah try my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put _id in static context its for previously clicked view. also add color white on your res/values/color.xml

```
    static int _id=-1;
```

here is the code..

```
    LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(context);
    lin.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);        
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
        final TextView btn = new TextView(context);
        btn.setId(i);           
        final int id_ = btn.getId();
        Log.i("id",""+id_);
        btn.setText("button " + id_);                       

        // btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
        lin.addView(btn, params);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*
                 * new_addonprice_name.removeAllViews(); String aaa =
                 * updatebutton();
                 */
                if(_id != -1)
                {                       
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(_id);                     
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);                                                
                }                   
                _id = id_;
                btn.setSelected(true);

                Toast.makeText(context, btn.getText().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);

            }
        });
```

Comment: hey thank for you ans. but i getting error in TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(_id);

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(_id);            this is not taking. this method need R.id.name of file or control

Comment: can't understand. did u create static _id globally.

Comment: yes. but now i solve my issue not 100% from you ans but yes 80% you help me that a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need the [selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024007/2413972).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
```

*res/drawable/new_button.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Comment: its not working... i creating dynamic button. if i setbackgroundcolor then its set to all button.

Comment: You write your TabHost?

Comment: Do you want to reset the styles other buttons?

Comment: i have one popup. over there i put that layout, in that layout i creating dynamic button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89004/discussion-between-tej-shah-and-user2413972).

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                {
            //final String check = "1";
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
                final TextView btn = new TextView(activity);
                btn.setId(i);
                final int id_ = btn.getId();
                btn.setText("button " + id_);
               // btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);


                //btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
                new_addonprice_name.addView(btn, params);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor") @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*                      new_addonprice_name.removeAllViews();
                        String  aaa = updatebutton();*/
                        //   btn.setSelected(true);\
                         //if(_id != -1)
                        for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                            {                       
                                TextView tv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(i);                     
                                tv.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);                                                
                            }                   
                           // _id = id_;

                        Toast.makeText(activity, btn.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                    }
                });
            }
```