# ImageButton selector does not working in Android

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have two imagebuttons in a LinearLayout with the following:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgImport"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bgselector2"
        android:src="@drawable/player_import" />

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/players"
        android:background="@drawable/bgselector" />
```

The selector on the second imagebutton works properly but **the first image button** with the following simple selector does not! Why is that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/players_import_pr" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: for default and press state one is enough?

Comment: do your linear layout have orientation attribute? it's possible is over the button, the other one... are you assigning the right file name to your your button?

Comment: Its a Linear with horizontal orientation containing a TextView,ImageButton,ImageButton

Comment: is recommended to only assign background attribute when using selector, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Answer (score 0):

Try to add android:state_pressed="false" for second state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/players_import_pr" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Or maybe you should have transparent as default item?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/players_import_pr" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```