# How to make checkbox looks like a button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

This image is from medium android application. The white boxes are the selected items. How can I make list of items like this and let the user select some of them in android?

[image: Image1]

Comment: Questions that are just a picture and "how do I make this?" are off topic (see [help/on-topic]) on StackOverflow. You should attempt yourself and then ask for help when you  have a _specific_ programming problem (i.e., some code)

Answer (score 0):

You can import two images and use one or the other depending on if the item is selected or not, for this you need to use a selector.

It´s like this one [android button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector),

Also, I recommend you to use a 9-patch images, you can see more about it here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

As the webpage says "They are bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen" so I think they would be perfect for your application