# How to style button for 3 different states

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to create my own version of Simon says. I want to create three states(colors) for the buttons; off(false), flashed pressed(true). If I use `mButton1.setbackgroundColor(Color.Red)`  I lose the XML button styling. How can this be done without losing the XML styling or is there a better way to style the buttons.

Comment: Use a `Selector` drawable.

Comment: [android button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `button selector` xml in `drawable` directory, something like below. It defines different drawables to use when button is at different states, eg: default, pressed, etc.

`drawable/my_button_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_pressed" />

    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_pressed" />

    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_pressed" />

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_default" />
</selector>
```

Then, define the respective `drawable xml` for different states:

`drawable/my_button_default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- define this color in your colors.xml  -->
    <solid android:color="@color/default_button_color"/>

    <!-- this makes the rounded corners button -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

`drawable/my_button_pressed.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- define this color in your colors.xml  -->
    <solid android:color="@color/pressed_button_color"/>

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

You can now use the `drawable/my_button_selector`, in the `xml` that defines the `button`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_selector"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="160"
    android:text="My Button" />
```

Note that for `API Level 21 or higher`, you can use the default `ripple` effect. Place the below `my_button_selector.xml` under `drawable-v21` directory:

`drawable-v21/my_button_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/ripple_material_light">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_button_default" />
</ripple>
```

With this, Android will use `v21/my_button_selector.xml` for `API Level 21 or higher`. For API level lower than that, it uses `drawable/my_button_selector.xml`.