# Click animation for a button with an image

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, onclick

I have this button, with transparent background, composed of an image and a text:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"
    android:text="@string/settings" />
```

When I click it, I would like to have a feeling of the click, like a blinking of the image.
I tried to do this with shapes, but their effect doesn't work on the image.
Can you help me?

Comment: you can use selector as a background to reflect click. [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manipulate the opacity of the Button using Animation when the button is clicked

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_SignIn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.5f); //to change visibility from visible to half-visible
        animation.setDuration(50); // 100 millisecond duration for each animation cycle
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); //animation will start from end point once ended.
        btn.startAnimation(animation); //to start animation
    }
});
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```