# How to Override material design statepressed in for Android Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, material-components-android

Hello Learned Friends,

I am using Material Design Theme but I need to overried its statePressed so that when the button is clicked it changes color (highlighted for a moment) as demonstrated below.

[image]

For this I have a drawable which I set on the buttons as follows

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/primaryDarkColor" android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />

    </shape>

</item>


<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/secondaryColor" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/secondaryLightColor" android:width="@dimen/stroke_width" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

I also got a ThemeOverlay to override the state pressed

```
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Red.UnitedStates" parent="">
<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    </style>
```

Unfortunately when I click the buttons the highlight doesn't happen.

What could I be missing?

This is Material Theme XML

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
```

Comment: How are you applying the drawable to the buttons? As background drawable? Also, how are you attaching your ThemeOverlay to your App Theme?
Note:
Your selector code doesn't seem to be right, the default state (not pressed) should always be at the bottom. So you should put state_pressed before default.
check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just the `app:backgroundTint` attribute:

```
     <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
          app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_button_selector"
          ../>
```

with:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red600" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Normal state:

[image]

Pressed state:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Gabriele, your solution is perfect, greatly appreciated.